# When agent hits double time in overtime accumulative over days

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I am trying to work out how many hours our department has in double over time hours.

When an agent has completed 10 hours of overtime they hit the double time overtime period. I am trying to calculate what day they hit the double overtime period as well as how many hours double time all agents have accumulated for this month.

doing this in excel I used a sum formula to get the sum of the hours for each agent but had to increase the sum range each day the agent did overtime. it was OK for one agent but when we have 150 agents this will not be viable.

```
Dataset

emp_Name        date    duration 
joe bloggs      1/10/2016   2.5 
joe bloggs      5/10/2016   2 
joe bloggs      9/10/2016   4 
joe bloggs      18/10/2016  7 
joe bloggs      26/10/2016  6 
andrew smith    1/10/2016   6 
andrew smith    5/10/2016   4 
andrew smith    9/10/2016   5 
andrew smith    18/10/2016  2 
andrew smith    26/10/2016  2 
andrew smith    29/10/2016  2.5 
Leanne Himms    1/10/2016   3.5 
Leanne Himms    5/10/2016   3 
Leanne Himms    9/10/2016   4 
Leanne Himms    18/10/2016  4.5 
Leanne Himms    26/10/2016  6 
Leanne Himms    27/10/2016  3.5 
Leanne Himms    29/10/2016  2 
john mcduffy    1/10/2016   2.5 
john mcduffy    5/10/2016   2.5 
john mcduffy    9/10/2016   2.5 
john mcduffy    18/10/2016  2.5 
john mcduffy    26/10/2016  6 
john mcduffy    29/10/2016  5
```

I can not picture a mental map of how I would go about this can anyone give me a clue as to how they would achieve this result?

Thanks In advance

Comment: please  improve question with sample data and expected result ,also tag the DBMS you are using

Comment: You didn't mention SQL or databases anywhere in your question.  Are you sure the SQL tag is appropriate.

Comment: I am trying to build a stored proc in SQL server 2005,

Comment: Expected result would be either a single row for each agent with amount of hours over the 10 hours and the date they reach the 10 hours 
or
a new column with a flag t indicate what day they went over the limit and hours they had after that period

Answer (score 1):

This should help you figure out what you're after using a `SUM OVER` clause:

Temp table for data:

```
CREATE TABLE #emp
    (
      [emp_Name] VARCHAR(12) ,
      [workdate] DATE ,
      [duration] DECIMAL(4, 2)
    )

INSERT INTO #emp
    ([emp_Name], [workdate], [duration])
VALUES
    ('joe bloggs',  CONVERT(DATE,'1/10/2016' ,103), 2.5),
    ('joe bloggs',  CONVERT(DATE,'5/10/2016' ,103), 2),
    ('joe bloggs',  CONVERT(DATE,'9/10/2016' ,103), 4),
    ('joe bloggs',  CONVERT(DATE,'18/10/2016',103), 7),
    ('joe bloggs',  CONVERT(DATE,'26/10/2016',103), 6),
    ('andrew smith',  CONVERT(DATE,'1/10/2016' ,103), 6),
    ('andrew smith',  CONVERT(DATE,'5/10/2016' ,103), 4),
    ('andrew smith',  CONVERT(DATE,'9/10/2016' ,103), 5),
    ('andrew smith',  CONVERT(DATE,'18/10/2016',103), 2),
    ('andrew smith',  CONVERT(DATE,'26/10/2016',103), 2),
    ('andrew smith',  CONVERT(DATE,'29/10/2016',103), 2.5),
    ('Leanne Himms',  CONVERT(DATE,'1/10/2016' ,103), 3.5),
    ('Leanne Himms',  CONVERT(DATE,'5/10/2016' ,103), 3),
    ('Leanne Himms',  CONVERT(DATE,'9/10/2016' ,103), 4),
    ('Leanne Himms',  CONVERT(DATE,'18/10/2016',103), 4.5),
    ('Leanne Himms',  CONVERT(DATE,'26/10/2016',103), 6),
    ('Leanne Himms',  CONVERT(DATE,'27/10/2016',103), 3.5),
    ('Leanne Himms',  CONVERT(DATE,'29/10/2016',103), 2),
    ('john mcduffy',  CONVERT(DATE,'1/10/2016' ,103), 2.5),
    ('john mcduffy',  CONVERT(DATE,'5/10/2016' ,103), 2.5),
    ('john mcduffy',  CONVERT(DATE,'9/10/2016' ,103), 2.5),
    ('john mcduffy',  CONVERT(DATE,'18/10/2016',103), 2.5),
    ('john mcduffy',  CONVERT(DATE,'26/10/2016',103), 6),
    ('john mcduffy',  CONVERT(DATE,'29/10/2016',103), 5)
```

Query the data:

```
SELECT  * ,
        CASE WHEN t.RunningTotal < 10 THEN 0
             ELSE t.RunningTotal - 10
        END AS HoursOver
FROM    ( SELECT    * ,
                    SUM(duration) OVER ( PARTITION BY emp_Name 
                                         ORDER BY emp_Name, workdate ) AS RunningTotal
          FROM      #emp
        ) t

-- tidy up
DROP TABLE #emp
```

Produces:

```
emp_Name        workdate    duration    RunningTotal    HoursOver
andrew smith    2016-10-01  6.00        6.00            0.00
andrew smith    2016-10-05  4.00        10.00           0.00
andrew smith    2016-10-09  5.00        15.00           5.00
andrew smith    2016-10-18  2.00        17.00           7.00
andrew smith    2016-10-26  2.00        19.00           9.00
andrew smith    2016-10-29  2.50        21.50           11.50
joe bloggs      2016-10-01  2.50        2.50            0.00
joe bloggs      2016-10-05  2.00        4.50            0.00
joe bloggs      2016-10-09  4.00        8.50            0.00
joe bloggs      2016-10-18  7.00        15.50           5.50
joe bloggs      2016-10-26  6.00        21.50           11.50
john mcduffy    2016-10-01  2.50        2.50            0.00
john mcduffy    2016-10-05  2.50        5.00            0.00
john mcduffy    2016-10-09  2.50        7.50            0.00
john mcduffy    2016-10-18  2.50        10.00           0.00
john mcduffy    2016-10-26  6.00        16.00           6.00
john mcduffy    2016-10-29  5.00        21.00           11.00
Leanne Himms    2016-10-01  3.50        3.50            0.00
Leanne Himms    2016-10-05  3.00        6.50            0.00
Leanne Himms    2016-10-09  4.00        10.50           0.50
Leanne Himms    2016-10-18  4.50        15.00           5.00
Leanne Himms    2016-10-26  6.00        21.00           11.00
Leanne Himms    2016-10-27  3.50        24.50           14.50
Leanne Himms    2016-10-29  2.00        26.50           16.50
```

Comment: thank you so much Tanner, that is perfect I can create a sub set of this which will give me what I need.

Comment: @David just a little thing, I just saw the additional info you added in the comments for the expected results. I didn't see that originally. You should have added that to the question as it's important information and I would have seen that the question was updated when I was posting.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to return the total hours of overtime and/or double overtime and the date the double threshold was passed you can use the code below.  This code also works if you have multiple month's data in your table:

```
declare @t table (emp_Name nvarchar(50), datevalue date, duration decimal(10,2));
insert into @t values('joe bloggs ','20161001',2.5),('joe bloggs ','20161005',2),('joe bloggs ','20161009',4),('joe bloggs ','20161018',7),('joe bloggs ','20161026',6),('andrew smith ','20161001',6),('andrew smith ','20161005',4),('andrew smith ','20161009',5),('andrew smith ','20161018',2),('andrew smith ','20161026',2),('andrew smith ','20161029',2.5),('Leanne Himms ','20161001',3.5),('Leanne Himms ','20161005',3),('Leanne Himms ','20161009',4),('Leanne Himms ','20161018',4.5),('Leanne Himms ','20161026',6),('Leanne Himms ','20161027',3.5),('Leanne Himms ','20161029',2),('john mcduffy ','20161001',2.5),('john mcduffy ','20161005',2.5),('john mcduffy ','20161009',2.5),('john mcduffy ','20161018',2.5),('john mcduffy ','20161026',6),('john mcduffy ','20161029',5),('joe bloggs ','20161101',2.5),('joe bloggs ','20161105',2),('joe bloggs ','20161109',4),('joe bloggs ','20161118',7),('joe bloggs ','20161126',6),('andrew smith ','20161101',6),('andrew smith ','20161105',4),('andrew smith ','20161109',5),('andrew smith ','20161118',2),('andrew smith ','20161126',2),('andrew smith ','20161129',2.5),('Leanne Himms ','20161101',3.5),('Leanne Himms ','20161105',3),('Leanne Himms ','20161109',4),('Leanne Himms ','20161118',4.5),('Leanne Himms ','20161126',6),('Leanne Himms ','20161127',3.5),('Leanne Himms ','20161129',2),('john mcduffy ','20161101',2.5),('john mcduffy ','20161105',2.5),('john mcduffy ','20161109',2.5),('john mcduffy ','20161118',2.5),('john mcduffy ','20161126',6),('john mcduffy ','20161129',5);


with cte
as
(
    select emp_Name
            ,year(datevalue)*100 + month(datevalue) as YearMonth
            ,dateValue
            ,duration
                        -- This windowed function calculates the running total up to this record
            ,case when sum(duration) over (partition by emp_name, year(datevalue), month(datevalue) order by datevalue rows unbounded preceding) >= 10
                    then datevalue      -- By substituting a futue date if they haven't hit the hours threshold yet,
                    else '29990101'     -- we can do a MIN of the date in the select statement below.
                    end as DateCheck

    from @t
)
select emp_Name
        ,min(DateCheck) as DateHit10Hours
        ,sum(duration) as TotalOvertimeHours
        ,sum(duration)-10 as TotalDoubleOvertimeHours
from cte
group by emp_Name
        ,YearMonth;
```